# Load Angular templates at runtime

Tags: angular, angular8

I developed an Angular webapp being used as a framework for interactive slideshows, that reads a JSON file and presents content. Instances of this framework are packaged up with said content and delivered to a client to be run on their servers.

What I want to know is if there is a way for Angular to load template files at runtime as opposed to caching compiled versions of them with the AOT compiler. My use-case is that there are a few components with HTML text (e.g. instructions) that I'd like our content authors to be able to edit on a whim without needing me to compile a whole new version of the app.

AngularJS attempted to load template files via AJAX and you had to configure or script it to AOT compile templates, I'm basically looking to do this in reverse for just a couple components.

Answer (score -1):

What you are probably searching for are "dynamic components" in angular, this article should give you a decent overview https://indepth.dev/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular/

In general, I would suggest implementing a few customization options that don't require loading and compiling new HTML code to allow for customization. Having users literally rewrite you app while using it seems more than a slightly bad idea.

Comment: The article you linked seems to cover the concept of creating entire components on demand; that isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking to have template files be loaded, read, and parsed at runtime like AngularJS does out of the box.

Concerns about user error and security are mitigated here because I'll define which components have editable templates, plus those who would have any write access to these templates is limited to the people I directly work with. I compile the app, they author the content and modify the templates, and then it's all packaged up to be put on the client's servers.